# Hebrew subtitles are gibberish

Tags: video, vlc, subtitle, hebrew

I tried adding subtitles to a video with gsubedit (gnome subtitles), but it's showing the subtitles as gibberish and also I opened the file and saw there gibrish.

I used the subtitle also in windows there they were in Hebrew, how can I make Ubuntu show my subtitles in Hebrew?

Thanks for helping! (:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the encoding of a subtitle file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277565/how-can-i-change-the-encoding-of-a-subtitle-file)

Answer (score 12):

I am using VLC player and had the same problem. I solved it by pressing the Tools tab, then open Preferences, then go to Subtitles & OSD -> change the default encoding to Hebrew (ISO 8859-8) (or whatever your language is).

Then restart VLC player. Hope it helps whoever see this post.

Comment: I chnaged it to utf8 and it also worked

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with heb sub here is what I did,:

installing Hebrew fonts packs:

```
sudo apt-get install culmus xfonts-efont-unicode xfonts-efont-unicode-ib xfonts-intl-european msttcorefonts
```

restart VLC and then choose Arial as the font and Hebrew (Windows-1255)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the [VLSub extension](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php?content=148752) for VLC. Use the following commands:

- mkdir ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/
- mkdir ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/
- cd ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/
- wget http://addons.videolan.org/CONTENT/content-files/148752-vlsub_0-6.lua

Next go use it in VLC's menus while watching a video.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the translation file encoding is one that your movie player does not recognise.
You might try different movie players - in some of them you can help the movie player by telling it the what is the translation file encoding.
or you can change the translation file's encoding with the command line tool named "recode".
I also read in gogle that you can change the encoding using kate or gedit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the Language Packs installed for the Hebrew language.
Go to the 'System Settings' app, choose 'Language Support' then in the new window that appears, choose 'Install / Remove Languages...'.

Tick the checkbox next to Hebrew and choose 'Apply Changes'.
Try playing your video with Hebrew subtitles now.

Comment: It's already checked, my system is in hebrew, but the subtitles file is in gibrish.

Comment: Then either the subtitles are corrupted or the video player does not support the language/format the subtitles are in.

Comment: how to make it support?

Comment: Try to install VLC Media Player.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution:

1. copy paste the subtitles to a Google doc
2. copy paste from google doc to a local file
3. save the local file

Answer (score 0):

In VLC app powered in Android tv
Subtitles > choose "Windows 1255" > Restart Application